# Flutter: retrieve log history from real time database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

**UPDATE**

i want to retrieve user log history in realtime from path Staff=>randomID1=>log=> randomID2
i want to display the the data from randomID2 in showDialog.

my path : `final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Staff');`

```
       child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          query: dataRef,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
              Animation<double> animation, int index) {

            var log = snapshot.value['log'];
            var dates = log.keys.toList();
            var key = dates[index];

            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Email             :  ${snapshot.value['email']}'),
                    Text(
                        'Mail Status   :  ${snapshot.value['mail-status'].toString()}'),
                    Text('Date               :  ${snapshot.value['date']}'),
                    Text('Time              :  ${snapshot.value['time']}'),

                    Text(snapshot.value['log'][key]['current-date']),
                    Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        subtitle: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            for(var i = 0; i<log.length; i++)...[
                              Text(snapshot.value['log'][key]['current-date'])
                            ],       
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          })),
```

[image: my realtime database]

my error:

> `Exception has occurred.`
> `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.`
> `Receiver: null`
> `Tried calling: []("current-date"))`

i dont know why it display the same key value
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
Text(snapshot.value['log'][index]['current-date'])
```

The `index` is going to be a sequential numeric value (0, 1, 2, 3, etc), while the keys in the JSON you show are formatted dates. So `snapshot.value['log'][index]` doesn't exist in the JSON and gives back `null`, which explains the error message you get.

---

To get the key at an index in the JSON, you can do:

```
var log = snapshot.value['log']
var dates = log.keys.toList();
var key = dates[index];
```

*Note: you may need to cast or convert some of the types in this snippet. If you get errors of that type, please try to resolve them by searching for the error message before commenting.*

And then you can use that `key` in:

```
Text(snapshot.value['log'][key]['current-date'])
```

Comment: what if I want to display all lists of data in log child? as i have many data based on current time and date.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there. Did you try the code/approach from my answer? What did you get when you did that?

Comment: i did. it display only one data not all list of data in child log. example in path 'log'. i have list of data 20220110095744:{date:2022-01-10}, 20230110095733{date:2022-09-22}. i want to display date from 20220110095744 and 20230110095733 in a listtile.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `index` that you get from the `itemBuilder`? If so, can you edit your question and add an update with the code of how you implemented the solution from my answer?

Comment: I have already updated my post. can you check it out..I'm sorry if keep asking the same question T.T

Comment: Did you check the values that you get from my code yet? For example, what is `key` at every loop of the iteration? Is that what you expect it to be, based on my answer? There is no need to be sorry, but you *will* need to do some debugging on your own here. Set a breakpoint on the first line inside `itemBuilder` and step through it line by line, checking all values on each line to see if they match what you expect them to be.